# Postgres : invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: ""

Tags: postgresql

I am new to Postgres DB. I am getting the error:

> invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: ""

when trying to run the below query from java. ":from_date" and ":upto_date" will be replaced with null while executing in java. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

```
select tm.*
from team tm
 and tm.schedule_finish  >=  (case
                                 when :from_date is null or :upto_date is null  
                                       then TO_CHAR(to_date(concat(TO_CHAR(LOCALTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1 month','YYYY-MM') , '-01'),'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD')
                                  when (date_part('year',age(:upto_date,:from_date))*12+date_part('month',age(:upto_date,:from_date)))>36 
                                    then TO_CHAR(to_date(concat(TO_CHAR(LOCALTIMESTAMP -INTERVAL '1 month','YYYY-MM') , '-01'),'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD')
                                 else TO_CHAR(:from_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')
                               end)::timestamp
```

Comment: How exactly are you passing those values to your query? Please **[edit]** your question and add the Java code.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Those params are date fields which are passed through java code. These params are not mandatory, so if there is no selection made in the date fields then null will be passed to the query. Right now i dont have the java code with me. Sorry.

Comment: If you really pass instances of e.g. `java.time.LocalDateTime` then the error you have can't happen. What data type is `schedule_finish` I assume that is `timestamp`?

Comment: schedule_finish  is a date field . Also after your suggestion i could narrow down the issue to  this - TO_CHAR(:date_from - INTERVAL '1 month','YYYY-MM-DD'). in the param empty string is getting passed like this - ''. i am trying to convert it to date but no luck. I am getting an error as 'invalid input syntax for type interval: "" '

Comment: If you want to convert a string to a date, use `to_date()` to `to_char()`

Comment: I tired doing it..but i get error again:

SELECT
TO_DATE( ''- INTERVAL '1 month','YYYY-MM-DD') NAA

FROM

DUAL



 invalid input syntax for type interval: ""

Comment: You need to convert the string **first** then subtract the interval `to_date(:date_from, 'yyyy-mm-dd') - interval '1 month'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit unclear to me what type those parameters have when passed to the query.

`TO_CHAR(:from_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')` suggests it's a `timestamp` or `timestamptz` value (e.g. passed as a `java.time.LocalDate` or `java.time.OffsetTime`)

However the error message seems to indicate that you are passing strings as parameters (which is a bit dangerous as in that case you rely on implicit data type conversion when calling the `age()` function).

Assuming you do pass strings, you can handle empty strings in the first WHEN part by converting them to NULL. That way the subsequent expressions don't have to deal with empty strings.

I would add an explicit conversion for the call of the age() function. You also don't need to call `age()` twice, you can compare the result directly with an `interval` constant `age(...) > interval '36 month'`. The back and forth between `to_date()` and `to_char()` just to get a timestamp value of the previous  month's first day is also unnecessary.

And if all the expressions in the `then` part already return a `timestamp` it's no longer necessary to cast the whole CASE expression to a `timestamp`

```
(case
   when nullif(trim(:from_date),'') is null or nullif(trim(:upto_date), '') is null  
      then date_trunc('month', LOCALTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1 month')
    when age(to_date(:upto_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), to_date(:from_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')) > interval '36 month'
      then date_trunc('month', LOCALTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1 month')
   else to_timestamp(:from_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')
end)
```

If you want to do any calculation with your "date strings", you have to convert them first:

```
to_date(:from_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') - interval '1 month'
```